Question on representations of infinite groups
Let $K$ be a field and $G$ be a finite group with $(\mathrm{char}(K), |G|) = 1$. By Maschke's Theorem, we know that all characters of a $KG$-module are nonnegative integer combinations of irreducible characters. Does this hold for infinite groups $G$? Are there easy counterexamples?
And as a side, introductory resources / surveys on representation theory of infinite group would be appreciated!
(Sorry if this has been asked, my Googling luck is not good today.)

Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional $K$-vector space on which $G$ is acting. Then as $KG$-module it will have finite composition series and the character of $G$ acting on $V$ will be sum of its characters while acting on the Jordan-Hölder factors.

@TonyPizza Is there an analogous theory for infinite dimensional $V$?

While the answer is affirmative, as seen above, in some sense it is the wrong question, since the character no longer determines the representation when it is not indecomposable.
